# How to discard the polynomials with small coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

I have a list like this

```
{(-0.12952142851754841` + 6.938893903907228`*^-18 I) - (17.525908000000005` - 4.975740737167372`*^-17 I) k1^2, (-2.914139090711302` - 1.3833455871105996`*^-17 I) - (3.6056850228887516`*^-15 + 1.7532479660249581`*^-15 I) k1^2}
```

There are some polynomials with tiny coefficients which I want to discard. The following result is what I want.

```
{-0.130` - 17.526` k1^2, -2.914`}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html):

```
expr = expr = {(-0.12952142851754841` + 6.938893903907228`*^-18 I) - 
    (17.525908000000005` - 4.975740737167372`*^-17 I) k1^2, 
 (-2.914139090711302` - 1.3833455871105996`*^-17 I) - (3.6056850228887516`*^-15 + 
    1.7532479660249581`*^-15 I) k1^2};

Chop[expr]
```

> {-0.129521 - 17.5259 k1^2, -2.91414}